# Can´t read value of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `_td_input` which gives me this log when I `console.log` it.

```
jQuery.fn.init(1)
0: input#addjobstarttime.form-control.timewidth.td-input
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)
```

What I need is to save the **id** `#addjobstarttime` in a variable in the end. How do I get to this information?

I tried to read the information with `alert(_td_input[0]);`, but that gave me only `[object HTMLInputElement]` back.

Regards

Comment: Really not clear what you are asking. Show us some code that reflects what you want to accomplish along with a more detailed explanation

Comment: `$('input#addjobstarttime').val()`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev which is same as `_td_input.val()` since it is the same element

Comment: what do you mean save? set to a variable? then you doing everything right. you cannot do it with alert , it won't magically parse your jquery object and print all those fields. Specify more what is your use case.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. No, I need the "id" of the field. "#addjobstarttime". Sorry for formulating my question inaccurate. The string: "input#addjobstarttime.form-control.timewidth.td-input" would be enough